# dynamically construct array

Tags: php

Hy,

I have a very big question . 
I have an array like this one `$array[0] = 12, $array[1] = 20, $array[2] = 18` and based on this array i want to give a value to this array `$array_go[12][20][18] = $value` because i'm building a recursive function to create a multidimensional array with lots of subarrays.

Thank you very much .

`P.S. : Is it more simple if I have a $variable = '[12][15][20]'; and somehow to create $array{$variable} = value ; because i can't seem how to do it ?`

Comment: Unfortunately for you, The quality of answers are going to be directly proportional to the quality of the question.

Comment: @pufos No need at all for profanity. Your unedited question was hard for me to follow as well, as the code example threw me off the scent.

Comment: I know that but at the end of the question I rementioned exactly what the real problem was . As a result I edited the question and removed the unwanted part . :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I can't really follow what you're asking as I think there is a lot of unneeded information obscuring your actual question.

For starters, you can try the following code:

```
function helper(&$array, $path, $value) {
  $parent =& $array;
  foreach ($path as $entry) {
    if (!isset($parent[$entry])) {
      $parent[$entry] = array();
    }

    $parent =& $parent[$entry];
  }

  $parent = $value;
  // make this $parent[] if more than
  // one $value will be added to the same path
}

$array_go = array(); // or use some other array you already have
helper($array_go, array(12, 20, 18), 1);
helper($array_go, array(12, 15, 20), 2);
helper($array_go, array(12, 10, 22), 3);

print_r($array_go);


/*
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [18] => 1
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [20] => 2
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [22] => 3
                )

        )

)
*/
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted ... sorry for the ambigous explanation i gave . I removed it.

Comment: is it simple if I have a $variable = `[12][15][20]` and somehow to create $array{$variable} = value ; because i can't seem how to do it

Comment: @pufos You'll have to write `$variable = array(12, 15, 20)`, which you then could pass as the 2nd parameter to the helper-function.

Comment: Ok I got that, but if I have a $var that contais the $arr's keys won't I be able to somehow add a value to that $arr+$keys = value ?

Comment: No, without some help of a function/class or anything you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Yoshi .. i have a recursive routing and I cannot `$array_go = array();` as it will clear all previous data .. what to do  ?

Comment: If you already have a variable, just use that one and drop the `$array_go`. If that's what you mean. The purpose of the helper function I've given is that you provide (as the first parameter) the array where you want values to be injected, as a second parameter the path to the value and finally the value as the last parameter.